# Extract text retaining links using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri, mechanize

How do I extract text from following `<p>` while retaining the `<a>` tags

```
<p>
  Some <a href="http://somewhere.com">link</a> going somewhere.
  <ul>
    <li><a href="http://lowendbox.com/">Low end</a></li>
  </ul>
  Some trailing text.
</p>
```

Output expected:

```
Some <a href="http://somewhere.com">link</a> going somewhere.
<a href="http://lowendbox.com/">Low end</a>
Some trailing text.
```

The only solution I can think of is overriding Nokogiri `text` method and recursing over the `children`, hoping some easy solution is around.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. See "[mcve]" and Jon Skeet's "[Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)". We need to see evidence of your effort. Did you search for a solution? If so, what did you find and why didn't it help? Did you write code? If not, why? If so, what is the minimum code you wrote that demonstrates the problem you're having. Without that it looks like you didn't try and want us to solve the problem for you, which isn't what SO is for.

Comment: What you want to do isn't hard, but it isn't straightforward either. You have to get the inner_html of the `<p>` tag, then promote the inner `<a>` to replace the `<ul>`. I won't write the code for you because it's in multiple answers on SO and in the Nokogiri tutorials and you didn't show effort. Show us what you wrote and we'll put in more effort to help you in return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a `ul` inside of a `p` like that so any attempt to parse that as html4 or html5 will fail. That leaves regex, which can solve this easy enough:

```
str = <<EOF
<p>
  Some <a href="http://somewhere.com">link</a> going somewhere.
  <ul>
    <li><a href="http://lowendbox.com/">Low end</a></li>
  </ul>
  Some trailing text.
</p>
EOF
puts str.gsub(/<\/?(p|ul|li)>/,'')

#  Some <a href="http://somewhere.com">link</a> going somewhere.
#
#    <a href="http://lowendbox.com/">Low end</a>
#
#  Some trailing text.
```